# Editable Cells in a Column with an arrayformula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to be able to edit cells in a column with an arrayformula, without having a REF error when I manually input a value into a cell within the column. Is this even possible?

Basically I have an arrayformula that fills column B with the value 0 if column A has the string "-". Sometimes though, the I need to manually enter a value into column B, but that throws a REF error. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no workaround. arrayformula needs to expand and to do this it needs to have a space. if you manually enter something into that required empty space then arrayformula cant expand so it throws #!REF error.

to solve your issue you will need a script that will mimic your arrayformula behavior. this way you can edit any cell in your range